# Upper case chapter titles in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

How to write the chapter titles in Upper Case in the table of contents ?

Comment: Some more information is needed. What document class are you using?

Comment: book document class

Comment: Using uppercase only seems a bad decision. Do you mean a combination of uppercase and small caps? (Small caps substituted for lowercase.)

Answer (score 6):

The only change is `\MakeUppercase`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}

\makeatother

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}

Blah, blah.

\chapter{Second}

Blah, blah.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Redefining `\chapter` doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: @egreg You are right. Redefining the whole definition is for educational purposes.

Comment: Thanks :) ... It works with \uppercase instead of \MakeUppercase

Comment: @Muhammad Strange: `\uppercase`? Are you using LaTeX2.09?

Comment: Your current solution only works for chapters in `\mainmatter`, but not for those in `\frontmatter` or `\backmatter`. You need to add `\MakeUppercase` also in the `\else` branch.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you! (Yes, I know: we do not use "thank you". Higly complicated!) Corrected.