# Upper case chapter titles, sections, subsections, list of tables and figures in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I used the resources here and it worked for me but still have errors on the list of tables and figures: [Upper case chapter titles in the table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109946/upper-case-chapter-titles-in-the-table-of-contents). I am using a document class prepared by D. Leif Anderson `\documentclass[nosmallcaps,toccaps,12pt]{csuthesis}`.

My modification:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}%
    \global\@topnum\z@
    \@afterindentfalse
    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \if@mainmatter
    \refstepcounter{chapter}%
    \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
    {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\MakeUppercase{#1}}%   
    \fi}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}%
    \global\@topnum\z@
    \@afterindentfalse
    \secdef\@section\@section}
\def\@section[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \if@mainmatter
    \refstepcounter{section}%
    \typeout{\@secapp\space\thesection.}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}%
    {\protect\numberline{\thesection}\MakeUppercase{#2}}%   
    \fi}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsection{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}%
    \global\@topnum\z@
    \@afterindentfalse
    \secdef\@subsection\@subsection}
\def\@subsection[#1]#2#3{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \if@mainmatter
    \refstepcounter{subsection}%
    \typeout{\@subsecapp\space\thesubsection.}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}%
    {\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}\MakeUppercase{#3}}%    
    \fi}
\makeatother
```

Your help is a lot appreciated...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Welcome! What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you just want the table of contents entries in uppercase? Then remove the definitions above, which are incompatible with the `csuthesis` class. The following lines should be sufficient: `\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tocsection[3]{\indentlabel {\@ifnotempty {#2}{\ignorespaces #1 #2.\quad }}\MakeUppercase{#3}}
\let\tocchapter\tocsection
\makeatother`
And similar for subsection.

Comment: This \documentclass[nosmallcaps,toccaps,12pt]{csuthesis} produces lowercase table of contents and I was trying to Make all Uppercase. I couldn't fix in the cls and removing as you suggested did not work for me...thank so much. More:the required format at my university is : http://graduateschool.colostate.edu/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/etd-TOC-Sample-Pages.pdf

Comment: @gernot your code worked for me.Thanks a lot. Few more: it keeps the chapter name as it is : as chapter 1: INTRODUCTION and CHAPTER 1: INTRODUCTION required and could not extend to appendix, list table and figures... Thanks again for your help!

Comment: \makeatletter \renewcommand\tocsubsection[3]{\indentlabel {\@ifnotempty {#2}{\ignorespaces #1 #2.\quad }}\MakeUppercase{#3}} \let\tocchapter\tocsubsection 
\makeatother

\makeatletter \renewcommand\toctable[3]{\indentlabel {\@ifnotempty {#2}{\ignorespaces #1 #2.\quad }}\MakeUppercase{#3}} \let\tocchapter\toctable 
\makeatother

\makeatletter \renewcommand\tocfigure[3]{\indentlabel {\@ifnotempty {#2}{\ignorespaces #1 #2.\quad }}\MakeUppercase{#3}} \let\tocchapter\tocfigure 
\makeatother

Comment: \makeatletter \renewcommand\tocsubsection[3]{\indentlabel {\@ifnotempty {#2}{\ignorespaces #1 #2.\quad }}\MakeUppercase{#3}} \let\tocchapter\tocsubsection 
\makeatother...is OKKKK. Not sure for list of tables, figures and appendix @gernot and  thanks again!

Comment: @user3749929 I will look at it in a few hours.

Comment: @gernot Did you get few minutes to check  ? Thanks a lot for your help. \makeatletter \renewcommand\tocsubsection[3]{\indentlabel {\@ifnotempty {#2}{\ignorespaces #1 #2.\quad }}\MakeUppercase{#3}} \let\tocchapter\tocsubsection \makeatother...is OKKKK.  I could not fix list of tables, figures and appendix and chapter 1: INTRODUCTION to CHAPTER 1: INTRODUCTION ....

Comment: In your post, you link to a document that effectively contains two different versions of a table of contents. So you want to realize the uppercase version, right? What made you decide for `csuthesis` as document class? No objections, I just want to know what's variable and what's fixed.

Comment: Oh..that upper case version for toc worked. But want similar line for list of table, figure, appendix etc....I am only to meet my university requirement and nothing special. Too late to change now. Need quick help@gernot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:** The following answer only makes sense in this particular case (if at all), with the double-patched document class `csuthesis.cls`. The lines below are workarounds for workarounds for ...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{csuthesis}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\maketitle{\scshape Abstract}{ABSTRACT}{}{}
\xpatchcmd\maketitle{\scshape Acknowledgements}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}{}{}
\makeatletter
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\renewcommand{\tocsection}[3]%
  {\indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\MakeUppercase{\ignorespaces#1} #2.\quad}}%
   \MakeUppercase{#3}%
  }
\renewcommand{\tocappendix}[3]%
  {\indentlabel{\MakeUppercase{#1}\@ifnotempty{#2}{ #2}.\quad}%
   \MakeUppercase{#3}%
  }
\let\tocchapter\tocsection
\let\tocsubsection\tocsection
\def\l@section{\@tocline{1}{0pt}{0pt}{}{}}
\def\l@subsection{\@tocline{2}{0pt}{2.5pc}{5pc}{}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
\renewcommand{\indexname}{INDEX}
\let\orig@caption\@caption
\def\@caption #1[#2]{\orig@caption#1[\MakeUppercase{#2}]}
\makeatother
...
```

> [image]
>   [image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{csuthesis}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\maketitle{\scshape Abstract}{ABSTRACT}{}{}
\xpatchcmd\maketitle{\scshape Acknowledgements}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}{}{}
\makeatletter
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\renewcommand{\tocsection}[3]%
  {\indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\MakeUppercase{\ignorespaces#1} #2.\quad}}%
   \MakeUppercase{#3}%
  }
\renewcommand{\tocappendix}[3]%
  {\indentlabel{\MakeUppercase{#1}\@ifnotempty{#2}{ #2}.\quad}%
   \MakeUppercase{#3}%
  }
\let\tocchapter\tocsection
\let\tocsubsection\tocsection
\def\l@section{\@tocline{1}{0pt}{0pt}{}{}}
\def\l@subsection{\@tocline{2}{0pt}{2.5pc}{5pc}{}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
\renewcommand{\indexname}{INDEX}
\let\orig@caption\@caption
\def\@caption #1[#2]{\orig@caption#1[\MakeUppercase{#2}]}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{The Title of This Thesis}
\author{The Author}
\departmentname{The Department Name}
\gradterm{The Grad Term}
\advisor{The Advisor}
\committee{The Committee}
\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract.
\end{abstract}
\begin{acknowledgements}
This is the abstract.
\end{acknowledgements}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
%\listoffigures
%\listoftables
\mainmatter
\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1]
\section{One}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
\rule{4cm}{3cm}
\caption{figure one}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{One one}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}
\rule{4cm}{3cm}
\caption{table one}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{One two}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
\rule{4cm}{3cm}
\caption{figure two}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Two}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}
\rule{4cm}{3cm}
\caption{table two}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Two one}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Two two}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[1]
\section{One}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{One one}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{One two}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Two}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Two one}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Two two}
\lipsum[1]
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 because I have just answered, in blissful ignorance, what seems to be the same question, presumably from the same person, about this hitherto-and-deservedly-obscure class, and we both deserve something for our pain.

Comment: I thank you so very much. This extraordinary!  Let me try and I will update you my progress @Paul I thank you so very much.

Comment: It did the magic. The only issue now is list figures and tables still all lowercase. I want all in the table of contents uppercased. Like: LIST OF TABLE....TABLE 1 ....TABLE 2....TABLE 3 etc. and FIGURE 1, FIGURE 2...I thank you very very much again!

Comment: @user3749929 Ok, done, this requires two more lines in the preamble, see above. I'm now off. If you need some more help, you will have to be patient for about 8 hours.

Comment: You have a great night or day. I thank you so very very very much. It is solved. Everything looks great now. I will update you if I have few more issues tomorrow.@gernot

Comment: @gernot I know you are off now. Just for when you are back!.. Abstract and acknowledgement headings are uppercase as required but lowercase in the table of contents probably conflicting with the cls I guess....thanks so much again!

Comment: @Solomon I added a few more lines that "solve" the problem at least for the version of `csuthesis.cls` that I have downloaded. The problem is that this class initially had everything in uppercase, then someone has apparently edited everything to `\scshape`, and now the patches try to get everything back to uppercase without interfering with the class file. Since I don't really know what your class file looks like and what you try to achieve the proposed code is a bit of voodoo.

Comment: @gernot I get error now but it works when I use with new cls version Dr. Lief Anderson sent me for Abstract and Akgmt. I have no idea why Bibliography is not same style/size with chapter headings. Let me try few thing and get back to you otherwise. I thank so much.

Comment: @Solomon If you experience further problems and need help, then you have to provide the `cls` file that you actually use as well as a sample document (a stripped down version of your thesis) that shows the problems.

Comment: I think it worked and I submitted. In case of any more formatting issues, I will do so. Thanks so much and it is really a lot of help.

Comment: For some reason  left and right margins are not right and Bibliography heading is not same style/size as as "Chapter" headings. Tried all possible and couldn't fix this issue @gernot.

Comment: I use \usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}

Comment: Please post the code of the document class that you use, `csuthesis.sty`, as well as a small document containing your preamble and some contents such that we see the problems that you describe. I downloaded a copy of a class called `csuthesis.sty` from somewhere on the internet, which has been apparently edited and patched by someone. So far we were lucky that it was similar enough to the one you use, but in one of your comments you say that you now use the "new cls version Dr. Leif Anderson sent me for Abstract and Akgmt", so chances are high that we are out of sync.

Answer (score 2):

I am more or less completely confused about what you want to do.

### LaTeX Classes

LaTeX uses "class" files, which are sort of templates. They are not interchangeable. Some are in very common use. Others are rare. They use different internal code. This means:

1. You **cannot** just assume that something you found somewhere that solved the problem in one class will also work in yours. Things about titling, sectioning, automated tables and so forth are quite likely to vary from class to class. So it's not surprising that you found the carrion-code you were trying to use didn't work.
2. If you are posting a question on here please make it clear what class you are using, because it may matter.

The class you are using is in fact, as some googling found out, based on the `amsbook` class, having been adapted by Dr Anderson, as he elegantly puts it

> to meet the bullshit requirements of the Colorado State University Graduate School for the formatting of theses and dissertations

If you don't have to meet those "bullshit requirements" you had much better use a more standard class. If you do, I suggest you don't set about redefining things in a class that meets said requirements.

However ...

### Change "List of Figures" to "LIST OF FIGURES"

If you want to do this, redefine `\figurename`

```
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
```

You can do the same with `\contentsname` and `appendixname`. In each case this is going to affect not only the way these appear in the table of contents but in the text as well, of course.

### Change the way List of Figures and List of Tables are printed ... in the table of contents only

If you want to have these uppercased in the Table of Contents, but upper and lower case in the text itself, then I think you need something like this. To my way of thinking this would be weird, but there you are.

```
\makeatletter
\def\@starttoc#1#2{%
\begingroup
\setTrue{#1}%
\let\secdef\@gobbletwo \chapter
\let\@secnumber\@empty % for \@tocwrite and \chaptermark
\ifx\contentsname#2%
\else \@tocwrite{chapter}{\MakeUppercase #2}\fi
\typeout{#2}\@xp\chaptermark\@xp{#2}%
\@makeschapterhead{#2}\@afterheading
\parskip\z@skip
\makeatletter
\@input{\jobname.#1}%
\if@filesw
\@xp\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
\immediate\@xp\openout\csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
\fi
\global\@nobreakfalse \endgroup
\newpage
}
\renewcommand{\tocappendix}[3]{%
\indentlabel{\MakeUppercase{#1}\@ifnotempty{#2}{ #2}.\quad}#3}
\makeatother
```

(All this goes in the preamble, before `\begin{document}`. It involves minor adaptation of code from `amsbook.cls`, which the sainted Dr Anderson adapted to meet what he accurately called the "dumber, uglier CSU standards".)

### A Tiny Rant

One of the beauties of LaTeX is that, ideally at least, some sensible typographical thought goes into designing class files. Weirdly inconsistent modifications like this take an inordinate amount of time and effort, with not only a limited positive return in terms of typographical beauty -- but a positively negative effect. Far, far, far, far better just finding a thoughtfully designed class and sticking with it than fiddling like this in order to produce **internally incoherent** and **typographically amateurish** documents, piling cobbled-together class files scavenged online with peculiar little (mal)adaptations designed in-house. That is not only *not* what LaTeX is about, it is what it is not about!

Comment: I thank you so much @Paul Stanley. I understood now and can't go go back. I am running out of time. Your help is extraordinary. I am using all of you guys input.

Comment: I'm glad we can help. In the future, please don't ask the same question twice! It just causes confusion.

Comment: (+1) for your effort and your rant deserves much more ;-) Give in to your anger :D